# how to wrap all request handlers in a wrapper function in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing an express application and instead of writing a try-catch block for each of the async request handler functions i wanna create a wrapper function that receives them as an argument and puts them in a try-catch block .

for example  instead of :

```
export const login = async(req,res,next)=>{
    try{
        // code
        } catch(err){
             //code }
```

I wanna do this :

```
export const login = tryCatch(async(req,res,next)=>{ 
// handler function code without try-catch block
}
```

my code for tryCatch function is like this :

```
const tryCatch = (func: RequestHandler): RequestHandler => {
    return (req,res,next) =>  {
        try {
            func(req,res,next);
        } catch(err) {
            next(err) //i'm forwarding the error to the express global error handler middleware to handle it in there
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i encounter an error for example duplicate-key error from mongodb.
the catch block didn't pick up the error. it doesn't even reach the catch block.
everything happens in the try block and when an error occurs my app crashes.

Comment: since `func` is `async`, maybe you need to `await func(req,res,next);`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your response. i've already tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: nothing at all? seems unlikely

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry my bad. that was actually the problem. i made the returned function async and added await before func(req,res,next). thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a error handler like so. This will run for all requests that result in an error. See The default error handler [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

```
function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
   customErrorHandler(err);
}
```

Comment: I assume you have some logic in `customErrorHandler` to match Errors and do some logging. You can also send some formatted response here if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use something like [express-async-handler](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler) and to register `customErrorHandler` as the [global error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers)

```ts
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";

export const login = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  // code
});
```

and

```ts
// must accept four arguments
const customErrorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  // just an example
  console.error(err);
  res.sendStatus(err.status ?? 500);
};

// register error handling middleware after routes
app.use(customErrorHandler);
```

---

Note: express-async-handler won't be required if you're using Express v5.